# how to query from two different tables linked by a foreign key

Tags: mysql, sql, select, join

[image: heres a table of diagnosis i want to query the diagnosis and count the number of patient_ID diagnosed by it. so it has to be one diagnoes with numbers of patient BUT the next picture comes in the complaint table part where the query has to be with a certain month only]

[image]

heres a table of diagnosis i want to query the diagnosis and count the number of patient_ID diagnosed by it. so it has to be one diagnoes with numbers of patient BUT the next picture comes in the complaint table part where the query has to be with a certain month only

Comment: What you have tried so far?

Comment: Does noone read tutorials/manuals any more these days?

Comment: What is the output you need and how are the tables structured and which DBMS?

Comment: whats the relationship between the two tables? is it `complaint_id` to `complaint_id` 1:1 or is it `patient_id` to `patient_id` one to one or something else?

Comment: may i ask why i have -2 on my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I guess* you need to join both tables by two columns: `complaint_ID` and `patient_ID`

```
SELECT  a.diagnosis, COUNT(a.patient_ID) totalAmidtted
FROM    diagnosis a
        LEFT JOIN admitted b
            ON  a.complaint_ID = b.complaint_ID AND
                a.patient_ID = b.patient_ID
WHERE   b.date_time BETWEEN 'fromDate' AND 'toDate'
GROUP   BY a.diagnosis
```

To further gain more knowledge about joins, kindly visit the link below:

- [Visual Representation of SQL Joins](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/33052/Visual-Representation-of-SQL-Joins)

*off-topic: you are filipino right? specifically bisaya `:D`*

Comment: @Belmark talking native language in SO is strictly prohibited. `:D` by seeing your example data.

Comment: haha.. sorry im just new here. yeah, silly me. hahaha. but thanks bro it solved my problem, we have same query what i lack is the comparison of patient_ID and complaint_ID